# What does "башо́к" mean?

Tags: перевод

I've heard "в бошке" during a singing class, one was referring to the head, or a part of it. What does it exactly mean?

Comment: [Башка](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%B1%D0%B0%D1%88%D0%BA%D0%B0)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The plural form of word `башка` (head [*slang*]) is `бошки` or `башки`.
In genitive it becomes `бошек` or `башок`.

The word `башка` has a Turkic root `баш` that means a head.
I don't know any other meanings of this word.

Answer (score 2):

Dmitry is right, in Russian this is the meaning. But it's rude and offensive. Its disdainful connotations are particularly pronounced in its plural form.

The word originates from Turkic languages where the origin word incidentally also means `a head` both as a body part and as a chief (person).

In the context of drugs usage `башка/бошка` is a slang name for cannabis female flower **head**.

Comment: Thanks, so no other meanings except for head?

Comment: another one is a head of cannabis, which i additionally mentioned, that's it

Answer (score 2):

Except for what Dmitry wrote, the word `бошка` also exists in the drug slang. It means "готовая к употреблению шишка конопли" (cannabis bump ready to use) or "семенная коробочка опийного мака" (boll poppy).